# Vectorize scalar multiplication in PixelAccess in PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to vectorize a scalar multiplication factor on PixelAccess object that I am currently doing in a **nested for loop**.

**Current Attempt**

```
original = Image.open('img.png')
TEMP = '/tmp/tmp.jpg'
original.save(TEMP, quality=90)
temporary = Image.open(TEMP)
diff = ImageChops.difference(original, temporary)
d = diff.load()
SCALE = 10

# Part to vectorize
WIDTH, HEIGHT = diff.size
for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        d[x, y] = tuple(k * SCALE for k in d[x, y])
```

Problem is the `PixelAccess` object is strutured in a way that it is a 2d array of 3-element tuples, which makes it unintuitive to fit into a numpy framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing individual pixels you could use build-in image ops: your scaling by a factor of `SCALE` can be done as adding the image to itself with a scale factor `scale = 2 / SCALE`, see [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.add):

```
diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2/SCALE)
```

On my computer this is 95 times faster for the provided example image.
Please note that the result will be clipped to 255.

Comment: On a 15.8MB Image - 
`# Old --> 6.44 s ± 59.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
`# New --> 111 ms ± 28.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: Although the plots look same, will run a check at pixel level and report

Comment: this works absolutely correctly!